# Python: How to use the debug information files in Visual Studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I am writing **Python** code in **Visual Studio 2010** using the excellent **[Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://pytools.codeplex.com/)**. I can set a breakpoint and step through my Python code. However, I cannot step into any standard library code of Python (step into `print()` for example).

I noticed that Python.org also [provides](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.2.2/) **Visual Studio debug information files** for every Python release. This is a ZIP files containing `.pdb` files for the Python release. What do I need to configure in Visual Studio 2010 to be able to use these `.pdb` files to step into standard library code of Python?

Comment: I know this won't help much but as a short term fix those of us without debuggers typically use `print` statements where we think the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't currently support mixed mode debugging (stepping from Python to C++).  There's a feature you can vote on to express your support: http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/210

I experimented with letting VS do the debugging multiplexing early during 1.1 development but there were some issues with that.  If someone wanted to implemented the feature "all" they have to do is create the native VS debugger and coordinate between the Python and native debuggers in a "reasonable" way.  We don't have any immediate plans to do this feature, but it is something that I'm sure we'll eventually tackle if no one else beats us to it.

Comment: Dino: Thanks. May I know what these Python .pdb files can be used for?

Comment: The PDBs are for the native code of the Python interpreter.  They're primarily useful if you're creating a native extension or you're embedding Python and need to debug into the Python runtime.  They make it particularly easy to just download the sources, download the PDBs, and then step through the interpreter source code w/o having to be able to rebuild Python.